# Como puedo cargar un cliente por defecto en mi v-select Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript

tengo un v-select en donde listo a los clientes registrados en el sistema... lo que no me gusta es que el select no tiene cargado un cliente por defecto..

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Cliente(*)</label>
                        <v-select
                            :on-search="selectCliente"
                            label="nombre"
                            :options="arrayCliente"
                            placeholder="Buscar Clientes..."
                            :onChange="getDatosCliente"                                       
                        >
                        </v-select>
                    </div>
```

tengo declarada esta variable
`arrayCliente: [],`

y tengo estos metodos
`selectCliente(search,loading){
                let me=this;
                loading(true)

```
            var url= '/cliente/selectCliente?filtro='+search;
            axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                let respuesta = response.data;
                q: search
                me.arrayCliente=respuesta.clientes;
                loading(false)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
getDatosCliente(val1){
                let me = this;
                me.loading = true;
                me.idcliente = val1.id;
            },
```

`
Como puedo hacer para que mi arrayCliente obtenga un valor por defecto y aparezca en el v-select?

Comment: Si el valor por defecto viene entre los datos del servidor puedes declarar en data una propiedad llamada client_id e inicializarla en null, en tu axios cuando cargas el listado de clientes, asignas a client_id el id del que quieres que sea el por defecto puedes hacerlo con un find, y tienes que modificar en el v-select y ponerle v-model="client_id" y creo ke con eso ya resuelves

Comment: Disculpa... podrías darme un ejemplo.. no se como usar el find... pues la verdad no soy novato en vuejs

Answer (score 3):

Tu componente deberia quedar de esta manera:

```
 <v-select
     @on-search="selectCliente"
     label="nombre"
     :options="arrayCliente"
     placeholder="Buscar Clientes..."
     @onChange="getDatosCliente"  
     v-model="cliente_seleccionado"                                     
 >
 </v-select>
```

Me imagino que **on-search** sea un evento por tanto va con **@** y **onChange** sea lo mismo, ese seria el primer cambio, el segundo sería añadir el v-model

Bien ahora en tu data debes añadir esa propiedad:

```
data(){
   return {
       cliente_seleccionado: null,
   }
},
```

Si ya tienes datos solo añade ese nuevo, sino pon tal como te lo puse aquí

Y lo ultimo seria hacer un cambio en la parte donde cargas la lista de clientes:

```
axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
   let respuesta = response.data;
   //q: search Esta linea tuya no tengo ni idea de que hace y no creo que funcione mucho
   me.arrayCliente=respuesta.clientes;
   //Asumamos que tu cliente por defecto es el que se llama Pedro
   me.cliente_seleccionado = me.arrayCliente.find(client => client.nombre === "Pedro");
   //Si lo vas a buscar por el id puedes cambiar client.nombre por client.id === al_id_que_sabes_de_antemano
   loading(false)
```

})

Espero que hayas podido entender

Comment: Si entendi mas o menos pero no me funciono..

Comment: ahora estoy mirando este ejemplo que hace lo que quiero... lo estoy tratando de adaptar a mi codigo https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/gpcykkeb/3/

Comment: sabes trabajar con el devTools de Vue???

Comment: hasle un console.log a me.cliente_seleccionado despues de cargarlo y ponme que te muestra, pk con lo que te puse deberia haberte funcionado

Answer (score 2):

ya no deberías utilizar los eventos :on-search y :onChange estos métodos han sido actualizados a @search y onChange desapareció para ser reemplazado por @input.
Información extraída de la documentación de Vue-Select:
https://vue-select.org/guide/upgrading.html#events-instead-of-callbacks

```
<v-select
     @search="selectCliente"
     label="nombre"
     :options="arrayCliente"
     placeholder="Buscar Clientes..."
     @input="getDatosCliente"                                        
 >

 </v-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo resolví de forma momentánea, pues no me gusta mucho pero funciona... Lo que hice fue hacer un `console.log(+JSON.stringify(respuesta.clientes));` en mi método selectCliente para saber como me trae los datos.. Despues declare una nueva variable con el formato json que devolvía mi console.log
`cliente_por_defecto: {"id":4,"nombre":"Ocasional","num_documento":"12345"}`
Después lo único que tuve que hacer es agregar `v-model="cliente_por_defecto"` a mi v-select y ya funciona... No me gusta esta solución pues no es muy practico..

Comment: Esta solución no es práctica, digamos que tienes que modificar en tu base de datos el nombre de tu cliente y ahora se llama Ocupacional, ya ese cambio implicaria que tu select no mostraria por defecto el que tiene que mostrar

Comment: Con el find del codigo que te habia puesto si le haces un console.log debes obtener lo mismo que le asignastes a cliente_por_defecto en esta respuesta. Otro detalle tienes que ver **me** de donde viene pk en tu codigo no lo vi, asocie que era referencia a la instancia del componente de vue donde estas. Si me es lo que te explike ahora, con me.cliente_por_defecto = respuesta.clientes.find(function(cliente){ return cliente.id === 4; }) te debe funcionar, puedes reemplazar el function por arrow function (=>) si sabes que vas a tener compatibilidad